# Function mapping into a Banach space is lipshitz if all linear functionals are lipshitz

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lipschitz-functions

This is  problem 3.14.10 from Conway's functional anaylsis (abridged): If $\mathcal{X}$ is a real Banach space with dual $\mathcal{X}^*$, and $(S,d)$ is a metric space, then show $f: S \to \mathcal{X}$ is Lipshitz if $L\circ f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipshitz for all $L\in \mathcal{X}^*$.

I've hit a road block in the proof I'm working on, inspired by a comment in this post: [Lipschitz map between metric and normed spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654672/lipschitz-map-between-metric-and-normed-spaces). Define $\phi: \mathcal{X}^* \to Lip(S)$ by $\phi(L) = L\circ f$, which is well defined by assumption, and $Lip(S)$ is the Banach space endowed with the norm $\|g\|_{Lip} = \sup_{x\ne y} |g(x)-g(y)|/d(x,y)$. It is fairly routine to show using the closed graph theorem that $\phi$ is bounded (take $L_n \to 0$ and assume $\phi(L_n ) \to y$. It follows from the triangle inequality that $y=0$.)

This is where I'm lost-- now we are supposed to conclude using Hahn-Banach that $f$ is indeed lipshitz. I cannot see how Hahn Banach can be applied here... What is the functional defined on a subspace that we are extending? Can anyone fill in the details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boundedness of $\phi$ says that $|L(f(x))-L(f(y))|\leq \|\phi\| d(x,y)$ for all $L \in \mathcal X^{*}$. This implies $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq \|\phi\| d(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks @Kavi Rama Murthy! One point/question here is that a final step is to show that if $|L(x)| \le M$ for all linear functionals $L$, then $\|x\| \le M$. The proof of this that I could think of is that if $\|x\| > M$, then there exists a linear functional with $|L(x)| = \|x\| >M$. In order to see this we note that there exists a Hamel basis including $x' = x/\|x\|$. Define $L( \alpha x' + \sum_v \alpha_v x_v) = \alpha$. The existence of a such a Hamel basis requires the axiom of choice. As a result, is this result sort of equivalent with the axiom of choice?

Comment: @LostStatistician18 You are right. Most analysis ts take Axiom of Choice for granted.