# A Lipschitz map universal with respect to factorization through it of Lipschitz functions.

Tags: metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions, universal-property

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Given a metric space $(Y,\rho)$ and a $1$-Lipschitz map $\varphi\colon X\to Y$, we say that a $1$-Lipschitz function $f\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ factors through $\varphi$ with a dilation constant $D>0$ whenever there exists a $D$-Lipschitz function $g\colon Y\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f=g\circ \varphi$.

My question is as follows. When one can guarantee, in terms of properties of the metric space $(X,d)$, the existence of $N\in \mathbb{N}$, $D>0$, and a $1$-Lipschitz map $\varphi \colon X\to \mathbb{R}^N$, where the space $\mathbb{R}^N$ is endowed with, for instance, the norm $\|\cdot \|_{\infty}$, such that the following "universal property" holds: any $1$-Lipschitz function $f\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ factors through $\varphi$ with the dilation constant $D$.

Clearly, such a property holds in a trivial way as soon as $(X,d)$ is biLipschitz embeddable into a Euclidean space. But nothing comes to my mind besides this. Is this the only case or there is some weaker condition?

Would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, unfortunetally, I came to a negative for me answer: any such a universal map is necessarily a biLipschitz embedding. The proof is more or less elementary.

Let me prove a more general statement: suppose for metric spaces $(X,d)$ and $(Y,\rho)$ and a map $\varphi\colon X\to Y$ there holds a property that for any Lipschitz function $f\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ there is a Lipschitz function $g\colon Y\to \mathbb{R}$ with $g\circ \varphi= f$. Then $\varphi$ is injective and its inverse map $\varphi^{-1}$ defined on its image $\varphi(X)$ is Lipschitz. I removed here the normalization of Lipschitz constants as in fact irrelevant.

First I show that $\varphi$ is injective. Suppose there are $x_1,x_2\in X$ such that $x_1\neq x_2$ but $\varphi(x_1)=\varphi(x_2)$. Clearly, there is a $1$-Lipschitz function $f\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$. It follows easily from the McShane-Whitney extension lemma. Thus, if for some function $g\colon Y\to \mathbb{R}$ we had $g\circ \varphi =f$, then we would have $f(x_1)=g(\varphi(x_1))=g(\varphi(x_2))=f(x_2)$, which is a contradiction. So, $\varphi$ is indeed injective.

Let $\psi\colon \varphi(X)\to X$ denote the inverse of $\varphi$, so $\psi=
 \varphi^{-1}$. Now my statement is reduced to the following one: if the post-composition of a map between metric spaces with any real-valued Lipschitz function is Lipschitz, then the map itself is Lipschitz. To prove this, I want to use a statement verified in [Lipschitz map between metric and normed spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654672/lipschitz-map-between-metric-and-normed-spaces). It is shown there that if the post-composition of a map from a metric space to a normed linear space with any continuous linear functional is Lipschitz, then the map itself is Lipschitz.

To reduce my statement to the one obtained in the mentioned post, I use the following standard fact: any metric space can be isometrically embedded into a Banach space. Let $F\colon X \to \mathbb{B}$ be such an embedding with $\mathbb{B}$ being a Banach space. Let $\lambda\in \mathbb{B}^*$ be an arbitrary linear continuous functional on $\mathbb{B}$. The map $\lambda\circ F$ is definitely Lipschitz, so by the assumption I made, the map $\lambda\circ F\circ \psi$ is Lipschitz. Since $\lambda $ is arbitrary, using the fact from the post, I come to the fact that $F\circ \varphi$ is Lipschitz. Since $F$ is an isometric embedding, the map $\varphi$ is also Lipschitz. Q. E. D.